# Group data via mySQL query structuring or w/ PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    participants.projID,
    project.title,
    members.email
FROM participants
LEFT JOIN project ON (project.id = participants.projID)
LEFT JOIN members ON (project.memID = members.id)
WHERE DATE(posted) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY participants.projID
```

which gets the data OK, but there's redundancy in some rows when project belongs to the same member's email.

I need to rewrite it in such a way that I will have all projects grouped together before I send it to a member, instead of sending one project at a time, sometimes more than once to the same member.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Can you post the table structure of all three tables? It's too hard to answer without it. Be sure to note which are the primary/unique keys.

Comment: Would you mind tossing a working example into http://sqlize.com/?

Comment: @hafichuk I tried: http://sqlize.com/88dcFGBwhD

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the result by member's email. Then in your PHP code, send email once if the projects belong to the same email address.